# Access append, find the records that are lost due to key violation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I made an excel file, I made it exporting an access table, then I edited the excel file being sure it only contained the records that I wanted to append to the original table. now if I use access and do: external data, new data source, from file, excel, and choose to append from the excel I made, this is the warning i get:
[image: the warning i get]

It says that there are 10 records that will not be appended and are lost due to key violation. What I really want to know is: what records are exactly lost?
So I can figure out what is not working.
If I do another new table from the mentioned excel, and try to append the content of that table to the previous one i get a similar warning from the query execution;
[image: warning from the query execution]

So the question is: how do you find in access the record lost due to key violation? reading here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958?ns=msaccess&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zac900&helpid=acmain11.chm922&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us is not helping me find that.
Right now 270 records are inserted and 10 are not, I need to know what those 10 are.

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste in some screenshots? It sounds like you may have duplicate keys (keys should be unique), or their is some key construction rule that your new key aren't complying with. BTW, are you editing existing rows, or just adding new ones?

Comment: i linked the screenshots in the text. i already checked the excel for duplicates and the table for primary keys and there arent

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Access, but I thought if an import included some "bad" records,  Access would put those in a error table so that you can see what didn't make it to the regular table. I think I also had to disable the primary key in tables to get imports to work. However, copy pasting seemed to work just fine.

Comment: I meant screenshots of the data (not just  the errors) before and after editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In access Import the excel in a new table.
Control that the datatypes are compatible with the table you want to append.
Build a query that shows the lines from the newly created table and the lines from the table you want to append that have fields containing the rows of the newly created table.
In order to do so, in the query editor right click every join condition you trace and choose to show only data present in the added table.
The option for me was the second: include all records from the new table and only those records from table i want to append where the joined fields are equal.
That worked for me and helped me find the 10 rows that were already there.

Answer (score 0):

It has been 20 years since I used Access, so take this with some salt.

The right half of the applicable part of the error message looks pretty damning to me:

> "... or they violate referential integrity rules for a relationship defined between tables."

To me that says you added 10 records that need connection to at least one other table in the database and they do not have a value that fits. Could, perhaps, be as simple as a data type mismatch, one would think. But that is the avenue I'd investigate.

As to the question of which records were lost, it shouldn't be hard to export the records and match them up to your original Excel import data, or the end result that you loaded back in, or between those two sets, depending upon what you still have and what the sizes of each suggest would be... smartest/easiest/smallest to work with.